# Numpy largest singular value larger than greatest eigenvalue

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Let

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[ 1., -0.5301332 , 0.80512845],
              [ 0., 0., 0.],
              [ 0., 0., 0.]])
```

`M` is rank one, its only non zero eigenvalue is 1 (its trace). However `np.linalg.norm(M, ord=2)` returns 1.39 which is strictly greater than 1. Why?

The eigenvalues of M, returned by `np.linalg.eigvals` are 1, 0, 0, but the singular values of M are 1.39, 0, 0, which is a surprise to me. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case the 2-norm of `M` coincides with the Frobenius norm, which is given by the formula `(np.sum(np.abs(M**2)))**(1/2)`, therefore we can see that:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[ 1., -0.5301332 , 0.80512845],
              [ 0., 0., 0.],
              [ 0., 0., 0.]])

np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(M**2)))
1.388982732341062

np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(M**2))) == np.linalg.norm(M,ord=2) == np.linalg.norm(M, ord='fro')
True
```

In particular one can prove that the 2-norm is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of `M.T@M` i.e.

```py
np.sqrt(np.linalg.eigvals(M.T@M)[0])
1.388982732341062
```

And this is its relation with eigenvalues of a matrix. Now recall that the singular values are the square root of the eigenvalues of M.T@M and we unpack the mistery.

---

Using a characterization of the Frobenius norm (square root of the sum of the trace of M.T@M):

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diag(M.T@M)))
1.388982732341062
```

Confronting the results:

```py
np.sqrt(np.linalg.eigvals(M.T@M)[0]) == np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diag(M.T@M))) == np.linalg.svd(M)[1][0]
True
```

Comment: I believe that is not true, the 2 norm is not the Frobenius norm. Check on `A = np.diag([1, 2 , 3.15])`.

Comment: @P.Camilleri In this particular case they coincide since M is rank 1. I expressed myself poorly

Comment: @P.Camilleri have you given a shot to the edited version of the post?

Answer (score 0):

second norm of a matrix the square root of the sum of all elements squared

```
norm(M, ord=2) = (1.**2  + 0.5301332**2 + 0.80512845**2)**0.5 = 1.39
```

to get the relation between the eigen values and singular values you need to calculate the eigen values of M^H.M and square root it

```
eigV = np.linalg.eigvals(M.T.dot(M))
array([1.92927303, 0.        , 0.        ])
eigV**0.5
array([1.38898273, 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Comment: As in the other answer, the 2 norm is not the Frobenius norm: check on `A = np.diag([1, 2 , 3.15])`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm, second norm of a matrix is the Frobenius norm. `Frobenius norm = Element-wise 2-norm`

Comment: @AlyHosny Element-wise 2-norm is not the matrix 2-norm. The 2-norm and Frobenius one coincide if and only if M has rank less than or equal to 1 (which is indeed the case here).

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal. In the general case, the singular values are not equals to the eigen values. This is true only for positive Hermitian matrices.

For squared matrices, you have the following relationship:

```
M = np.matrix([[ 1., -0.5301332 , 0.80512845],
              [ 0., 0., 0.],
              [ 0., 0., 0.]])
u, v= np.linalg.eig(M.H @ M) # M.H @ M is Hermitian
print(np.sqrt(u)) # [1.38898273 0.         0.        ]
u,s,v = lin.svd(M)
print(s) # [1.38898273 0.         0.        ]
```